# Sync filesystem in background

Tags: linux, hard-drive

While coding Python, I tend to save files very often (I have a pretty high `code->test->code->test->...` frequency). I hate when Linux syncs my changes to disk everytime I do a write.

How do I configure Linux so that it keeps file writes in memory for a certain period of time/number of writes?

To make this any useful, of course reads to not-yet-fsynced files must be from memory (so that the Python interpreter always sees the latest contents). Extra credits for background-fsyncing that doesn't block other writes/reads going on at the same time :-)

Comment: That sounds like a problem with your editor...

Answer (score 4):

Normally Linux *always* caches disk writes for some time, but this depends on the filesystem's mount options. Make sure the filesystem is mounted in **`async`** mode, by checking `findmnt` or `/proc/mounts`.

- Good: `/dev/sda4 /home btrfs rw,relatime 0 0`
- Bad: `/dev/sda4 /home btrfs rw,sync,relatime 0 0`

If your disk has been mounted in *sync* mode for some reason, use this command for a temporary fix, and adjust your configuration in `/etc/fstab` to make it permanent:

```
mount -o remount,async /home
```

(Substitute `/home` with the actual filesystem root – possibly just `/` in a single-partition setup.)

---

Most often, though, the extra fsyncing is done by your text editor – Vim in particular does this for both actual file and the swapfile. Use the [`fsync`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27fsync%27) and [`swapsync`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27swapsync%27) options in *vimrc* to control it:

```
set nofsync swapsync=
```

For Emacs, you can set [`write-region-inhibit-fsync`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/emacs/Customize-Save.html).

---

[This article](http://shaver.off.net/diary/2008/05/25/fsyncers-and-curveballs/) describes Linux `fsync()` behavior in Firefox, and also mentions that ext3 (not ext4) can cause very long delays when the filesystem is mounted in `data=ordered` mode:

> On some rather common Linux configurations, especially using the ext3 filesystem in the “`data=ordered`” mode, calling fsync doesn’t just flush out the data for the file it’s called on, but rather on *all the buffered data for that filesystem.*

If you are using ext3 in this mode, consider disabling it.